# Stochastic difference equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, time-series

I am a newbie in studying time series. Could anyone help solve the following problem:

1. Consider the second-order stochastic difference equation: $y_t=1.5y_{t-1}-0.5y_{t-2}+\varepsilon_t$. Given initial conditions for $y_0$ and $y_1$, find $y_t$ in terms of $\{\varepsilon_t\}$ sequence.
2. Find the forecast function for $y_{T+s}$ given the value of $y_T$ and $y_{T-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{matrix}
y_t-y_{t-1}&=&0.5(y_{t-1}-y_{t-2})+\varepsilon_t\\
0.5(y_{t-1}-y_{t-2})&=&0.5^2(y_{t-2}-y_{t-3})+0.5\varepsilon_{t-1}\\
&\vdots&\\
0.5^{t-2}(y_2-y_1)&=&0.5^{t-1}(y_1-y_0)+0.5^{t-2}\varepsilon_2
\end{matrix}
Summing up the LHS and RHS gives $$y_t-y_{t-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{t-2}0.5^i(y_{t-i}-y_{t-i-1})=\sum_{i=1}^{t-1}0.5^i(y_{t-i}-y_{t-i-1})+\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}0.5^i\varepsilon_{t-i}$$
so $$y_t-y_{t-1}=0.5^{t-1}(y_1-y_0)+\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}0.5^i\varepsilon_{t-i}$$
Then 
\begin{align*}
y_t=\sum_{i=1}^t(y_{t-i+1}-y_{t-i})+y_0=&\sum_{i=1}^t\left(0.5^{t-i}(y_1-y_0)+\sum_{j=0}^{t-2}0.5^j\varepsilon_{t-j}\right)+y_0\\
=&(y_1-y_0)\sum_{i=1}^t0.5^{t-i}+t\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}0.5^i\varepsilon_{t-i}+y_0\\
=&\frac{1-0.5^t}{0.5}(y_1-y_0)+t\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}0.5^i\varepsilon_{t-i}+y_0\\
=&(2^{1-t}-1)y_0+(2-2^{1-t})y_1+t\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}0.5^i\varepsilon_{t-i}
\end{align*}

Comment: Smart trick :-), it's always Easy when you know how LOL!

Comment: @Stochastically, thanks, I had managed to do the first part when I posted this question, that was what I meant I could find $y_t$ in terms of $y_{t-1}$ and something. But later I woke up this morning I found I could slightly extend the trick more. Then I am done!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to give a full answer, but for part (1), it's just an AR(2) process, see e.g. [Autoregressive model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model#Autoregressive_model) on wikipedia.  So you can solve by writing in terms of the lag operator, etc.

Comment: I believe the final answer can be without any lag operators. But the way I tried always end up getting $y_t$ in terms of $y_{t-1}$ and $\varepsilon_t$, which is not enough.

Comment: I think you can use $$\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i $$ where x is the expression containing your lag operators, and hence write in terms of the $\epsilon_t$

Comment: does $L\varepsilon_t=\varepsilon_{t-1}$? And how can I make use of the initial condition?

Comment: Yes indeed, $L\varepsilon_t=\varepsilon_{t-1}$.  Although on second thoughts, perhaps the lag operator approach won't work for this question because it's not immediately obvious how to impose the initial condition.  As an alternative, I'd write out the first few $y_t$ and try and spot the pattern, then prove by induction :-).

Comment: I have found my way to do it!